# MVC who should pass parent view to the child in GUI?

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, model-view-controller

I am trying to implement an application where i need the GUI framework to be easily swappable, so i decided to use a model-view-controller approach, and to keep the controller unchanged when swapping the view component, i decided to make the view responsible for contacting whatever GUI framework is used (tkinter,QT,web), the design is summarized in the image below.

[image: model summary photo]

Since the view element of the parent and the child will be created separately, they will need to be linked in order to be rendered, and the component that links them needs to know about both the parent and the child's view objects and how they work, so whose responsibility is it to link them ?

The code looks as following, using Pyside2 as an example, the locations where the parent gui can be linked to the child is all commented out.

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QWidget

class parentView:
    def __init__(self):
        self.gui = QWidget()
        # framework specific code to initialize layout
    def add_child(self,child):
        pass
        # child.gui.parent = self.gui
        # child.parent = self.gui

class parent_controller:
    def __init__(self):
        self.view = parentView()
        self.gui = QWidget()
        self.child = child_controller(self)
        # self.child.view.gui.parent = self.view.gui ?
        # self.view.add_child(self.child.view.gui) ?
        # self.view.add_child(self.child.view) ?

class childView:
    def __init__(self, controller):
        self.controller = controller
        self.gui = QWidget()  # QWdiget(self.parent.view.gui) ?
        # self.gui.parent = self.parent.view.gui ?

class child_controller:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.view = childView(self)
        # self.view.gui.parent = self.parent.parent.view.gui ?
```

Creating the link in the parent view makes sense to me as i can make it do a framework-specific logic when the framework is changed, but i wanted to know what is best in terms of ease of use and maintainability, as i think i am creating too many objects.